# Karma Jasmine: Same Function Name, Two different source files

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have 2 source files to test:

- a.js
- b.js

They both have a function validate();

In writing bSpec.js and testing b.js's validate function, I find that a.js's validate is the one being called.  Do I have a way to specify which source file is the one to be tested?

both a.js and b.js are included in the karma-config via the files block using 'js_files/**/*.js'

Comment: What are the contents of these file?

Comment: I don't believe there is (In Javascript anyway, I'm not familiar with Karma/Jasmine so can't speak on behalf of that). What you can do though if `validate()` is being called in a.js instead of b.js then you can change the function name to `validateA()` or `validateB()`.

Answer (score 1):

When importing both files try providing each with an alias and use that to run the method you want.

Something like:

`import * as fileA from './a.js'`

`fileA.validate();`